# How can I prove that it is an Entire Function

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, entire-functions

Prove that if

$$
f(z)=\left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
   \frac{\cos z}{z^2-(\pi /2)^2} & \hbox{when} \; z\neq \mp \pi/2\\
    -\frac{1}{\pi}, & \hbox{when} \;z= \pi/2.
  \end{array}
\right.
$$

then $f$ is an entire function.

Comment: $$f(z)=-\frac{4}{\pi^2}\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{4z^2}{\pi^2(2n+1)^2}\right).$$

Comment: How can ı find the series of this function.

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS:**

$$\frac{1}{z^2-(\pi/2)^2}=\frac1\pi \left(\frac{1}{z-\pi/2}-\frac{1}{z+\pi/2}\right)$$

and

$$\cos(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(z-\pi/2)^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$$

and

$$\cos(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{(z+\pi/2)^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. If the answer is not useful, I am happy to delete. Please advise. -Mark